# Wonky diagrams in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm trying to make a commutative diagram (without the package tikz-cd) with nodes of different sizes.

I'm skipping nodes like this

```
  &   & A &   &   \\
  & B &   & C &   \\
D &   & E &   & F \\
```

and would like to add diagonal arrow e.g. `A -- B -- D`, but for some reason they don't run in a straight line.

I'm already using `column sep = [fixed value]` to straighten it up, but the diagonal arrows a still a little wonky.

What should I do to straighten them out?

---

Here's my full code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-2.6pt,description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, column sep=3em]
{
&& A_1 && \\
& A_1 && A_1 \oplus A_2 & \\
A_1 && A_1 \oplus A_2 && A_2 \\
};
\path[-stealth,line width=.5pt,font=\scriptsize]
(m-1-3) edge node[above] {$id$} (m-2-2)
(m-1-3) edge node[above] {$i_1$} (m-2-4)
(m-2-2) edge node[above] {$id$} (m-3-1)
(m-2-2) edge node[above] {$i_1$} (m-3-3)
(m-2-4) edge node[above] {$id$} (m-3-3)
(m-2-4) edge node[above] {$p_2$} (m-3-5)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Why not `tikz-cd`?

Comment: @egreg I just managed to do everything I needed without it and never bothered to learn the syntax. Is it not an issue with tikz-cd?

Comment: @Earthliŋ Yes, it is too, because it uses the same engine. I managed to get arrows almost on a straight line by pretending `A_1`  to occupy the same space as `A_1\oplus A_2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-2.6pt,description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, column sep=3em, row sep=2em,minimum width=4em]
{
&& A_1 && \\
& A_1 && A_1 \oplus A_2 & \\
A_1 && A_1 \oplus A_2 && A_2 \\
};
\path[-stealth,line width=.5pt,font=\scriptsize]
(m-1-3) edge node[above] {$id$} (m-2-2)
(m-1-3) edge node[above] {$i_1$} (m-2-4)
(m-2-2) edge node[above] {$id$} (m-3-1)
(m-2-2) edge node[above] {$i_1$} (m-3-3)
(m-2-4) edge node[above] {$id$} (m-3-3)
(m-2-4) edge node[above] {$p_2$} (m-3-5)
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. Is there a way to make the arrows on the smaller nodes not stop short?

Comment: Add `inner sep=2pt` after `minimum width=4em` ?

Comment: That works perfectly and resolves a question I had for a very long time. Thank you!